# Can I syphon power from a USB-C smartphone and still charge the phone?

Tags: power, usb, basic, usb-c, smartphones

I'm designing a device (simple 5V LED) that will be powered by a smartphone (via the USB C socket). I am struggling with allowing the phone to be charged at the same time via the same connection.

Is it as simple as connecting all the pins in a passthrough and just connecting my LED between VBUS and GND?  I can't seem to get it to work - am I overthinking this?

[image: high level diagram]

I found these (http://www.adt.link/product/UTT-20G.html) that seem to do some of what I want, but I don't understand enough to know what all the extra electronics on the boards are doing.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It should work fine, just do not forget a current limiting resistor for the LED.

Comment: But what do you want your LED to do if the charger gets unplugged?

Comment: You want to power your led from an OTG type connection from the phone providing power, and then if you connect a charger, switch to that instead? You will need a way to control the USB connection on the phone to get it to be the upstream or downstream depending on the charger. Typically a microcontroller and some routing device like diodes or transistors or a dedicated usb c power IC. Or use a switch to manually change between the modes.

Comment: Yes exactly:  (1) when no external power is connected, LED is powered by phone, (2) when external power is connected, the phone charges, and the LED is powered either by the phone or the charger (not sure if it matters which!).  I'd prefer to avoid a manual switch if possible - can it be done automatically?

Comment: Did you have a chance to become familiar with USB Type-C connector specifications? Did you notice the function of CC pin, pull-up, pull-downs, and other such things, and their role in defining who is power provider, and who is power consumer?

Comment: No, thank you.  I'll keep looking!